# If $X$ is infinite dim'l and subspaces $N \subseteq M$ satisfy $\dim(X/M)=\dim(X/N) \lt \infty$, then $N=M$ holds.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional vector space and $N$, $M$ be subspaces of $X$ such that $N \subseteq M$. Suppose $\dim(X/M)=\dim(X/N) \lt \infty$. Show that $$N=M$$ holds.

I know that above holds if $X$ is finite dimensional by using the dimension theorem to show $\dim(N)=\dim(M)$. However, I do not see a way in the infinite dimensional case.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical linear map $X/N \to X/M$, $x+N \mapsto x+M$ is obviously surjective and because of both spaces are of the same finite dimension it is also injective. This implies $M=N$.

Comment: How does it imply $M=N$?

Comment: I think I got it. If $m \in M - N$, then   $M \mapsto m+N$ which is impossible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We have a natural surjective map $X/N\to X/M$.